# Using a common functionality in two different projects of .net core and angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have two existing projects, one on .net core (Project1) and other on angular (not AngularJS)(Project2).

I have to create a new project(Project3) which will have a [pricing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/pricing/) functionality and that is to be used in both of the above mentioned projects.

I want to ask that on which language should Project3 be developed so that its views and other functionalities can be accessed by Project1 and Project2 and how can we access Project3 from these two projects

Comment: For the Project 3, you could create a .net core API application, then access its view or action method.

Comment: I can use the action and views of Project3 in Project1, but how will I use it in Project2.
Project2 is a pure angular project which uses an API in the backend

Comment: In Project 2, you could use the Http service to call the API function, for the View page, you could get the html content, then, dynamically populate them in the angular page.

Comment: yeah that sounds nice. I will try that. Thanks